# query within the sub-query in doctrine2 query builder not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a following table structure

TABLE : doctors

```
id name 
1  Mac
2  Smit
```

TABLE : Organizations

```
id name
1  Org1
2 Org2
```

TABLE : org_doctors

```
id org_id doctor_id
1   1      1
2   1      2
```

TABLE : specializations

```
id name
1 ENT
2 Cardiac
```

TABLE : doc_specialzations

```
id doctor_id specialzation_id
1  1          1
2  1          2
3  2          1
```

Below is the doctrine code i am working in:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb2 = $qb;
    $qb2->select('dsp.doctor_id')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\DoctorSpecialization', 'dsp')
            ->where('dsp.specialization = :specializationId')
            ->setParameter('specializationId', $searchBy['specialization']);


    $qb->select('od', 'd', 'o', 'u')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor', 'od')
            ->leftJoin('od.organization', 'o')
            ->leftJoin('od.doctor', 'd')
            ->leftJoin('d.user', 'u');


    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('od.doctor', $qb2->getDQL()));

$qb->andWhere('od.organization IN (:organizations)')
                ->andWhere('d.active = true')
                ->andWhere('od.active = true')
                ->setParameter('organizations', $organizations);
```

When working on the abvoe code, i am getting the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 188: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','
```

This is my DoctorSpecialization Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="doctors_specializations")
 */

class DoctorSpecialization extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctor\Entity\Doctor", inversedBy="docSpecialization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="doctor_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    protected $doctor;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctor\Entity\Specialization", inversedBy="docSpecialization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="specialization_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $specialization;

    public function setDoctor(Doctor $doctor = null)
    {
        $this->doctor = $doctor;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDoctor()
    {
        return $this->doctor;
    } 

    public function setSpecialization(Specialization $specialization = null)
    {
        $this->specialization = $specialization;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSpecialization()
    {
        return $this->specialization;
    }  

}
```

Comment: This error means you have a synthax error somewhere, try to isolate problem will help u.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code... IMO in yours there are mistakes...

```
    //don't use the same query builder for the two querys
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb2 = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb2->select('dsp.doctor')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\DoctorSpecialization', 'dsp')
            //You are searching by specializationId so join with especialization
            ->leftJoin('dsp.specialization', 'esp')
            ->where('esp.id = :specializationId')
            ->setParameter('specializationId', $searchBy['specialization']);


    $qb->select('od', 'd', 'o', 'u')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor', 'od')
            ->leftJoin('od.organization', 'o')
            ->leftJoin('od.doctor', 'd')
            ->leftJoin('d.user', 'u');

    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('od.doctor', $qb2->getDQL()));
    //If organizations is an array of ids => o.id... if is an array of entities your code where rigth here
    $qb->andWhere('o.id IN (:organizations)')
                ->andWhere('d.active = true')
                ->andWhere('od.active = true')
                ->setParameter('organizations', $organizations);
```

Good luck

**Note**: *You could also declare doctor_id and specialization_id as private/protected properties in your entity with @ORM/Column annotations, that doesn't conflict with the relations already declared and facilitates the queries as you don't had to join with the entity (in this case especialitation), but I don't know if it is very good practice*

Comment: Thanks @Edu, while i am trying that, i am getting the following error. [Semantical Error] line 0, col 145 near 'doctor_id FROM': Error: Class Doctor\\Entity\\DoctorSpecialization has no field or association named doctor_id

Comment: Could you post your entities?

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, I was thinking yesterday about the question and you don't need a subquery, simply two more joins and modify the query clause

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('od', 'd', 'o', 'u')
        ->from('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor', 'od')
        ->leftJoin('od.organization', 'o')
        ->leftJoin('od.doctor', 'd')
        ->leftJoin('d.doctor_specialization', 'dsp')
        ->leftJoin('dsp.specialization', 'esp')
        ->leftJoin('d.user', 'u');

$qb->where('esp.id = :specializationId')
//If organizations is an array of ids => o.id... if is an array of entities your code where rigth here
   ->andWhere('o.id IN (:organizations)')
            ->andWhere('d.active = true')
            ->andWhere('od.active = true')
            ->setParameter('specializationId', $searchBy['specialization'])
            ->setParameter('organizations', $organizations);
```

Good luck